# What does "your authors" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In a book 
*[Engineering Software as a Service: An Agile Approach Using Cloud Computing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19dqWms9qUQ2Bi8JfsBhC5Q6zDeJd0s5o/view)*, "your authors" is repeatedly used, for example:

> But while pair
> programming emerged as a practice used by Agile teams and developers, **your authors** believe
> it’s also a way to accelerate the learning of a new language and framework.

What does "your authors" mean? Does that mean the book's authors? In that case, why is "your" used? I'm not sure if the authors are mine.

Comment: It might be intended to give an informal touch to the book. It is usually 'the authors' but the objection isn't true. If you are reading a library book you can say "I put down my book" even though it isn't your property. Similarly "Your hosts welcome you to the party" where they aren't *your* hosts but the party's hosts.

Comment: 'Your _something_' can be used about a person or persons who are doing something for you - your chef, waiter, driver, pilot, players (in a play in the theatre), and here, author[s].

Comment: At a theatre where a number of acts are introduced by someone: "Ladies and gentlemen! Welcome to tonight's show! Your host [or master of ceremonies] tonight will be me, Melvin Jennings!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By reading the book you have a relationship (admittedly tenuous) with the authors of the book. The phrase *your authors* emphasises this relationship.

Another way of emphasising the relationship would be the practice of some authors who would directly address the reader as *dear reader*.

Both expressions declined after the 1860s, but both have become more popular in the last 20 years.